# Land cover change maps - Different extent when adding a New data frame in layout view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extents, layouts, land-cover

I would like to create a map where I show land cover change between year 1996 and 2002 in Indonesia. In the layout view, I added a new data frame to add the other year, but it seems that the extent is different in the first Layer than the extent of the"New data frame". At the very beginning,I used the Raster Project to change the spatial reference (used Eckert IV) so that they would also have a linear unit in meters, and not only angular unit, which is in degrees. However, the extent of the ''New data frame'" is in meters, but the "Layer frame"" is in degrees. What do I need to do to make sure that all my maps have the same extent in each Data frame I add?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: You likely need to be reprojecting your layers to all match the same CRS.

Comment: @PolyGeo I work with arcGIS (version 10.4.1) and I reprojected all my maps before I began working with them. The extent of all my maps are the same under the main "layer"', where I now have the linear unit in meters, and the angular unit in degrees. But when I open one map (say 1996) in the layout view under the main "'layer"', the extent is shown in degrees. And when I add a new data frame, the same map (1996) is shown in meters.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ArcGIS, Go to data frame properties

Then Data Frame >> Extent >> Other data frame >> Layers

You can also specify units.

[image]